# How to get the value of an item from a list field to add it to a computed field

Tags: entities

I am on Drupal 7 and I have issue. I want to set a **token** system that will make people buy **token from their user account settings** in order to be able to do some particular actions on the site.

So I've created three fields in the user's form with the help of [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds):

- **field_buy_tickets** (Yes/No) : Yes if the user wants to add more tickets. If "Yes", field "field_nb_of_tickets" appears.
- **field_nb_of_tickets** : is a list of numbers from 1 to 9 that the user choose one item.
- **field_avoir** : When the user Save the changes, the number in the item chosen in "field_nb_of_tickets" should be added to the this field_avoir. I chose this field to be "computed" because I want the new value to be added to the old one, not to override it.

I was sure that it would work well, **but I get an error**. After a few time trying to make it work, I am **still at the same point**.

Can somebody help ?

**Here are some pictures to illustration the case**:

**1. The first 2 fields**
[image: 1. Buy ticket' and Nb of tickets' fields]

**2. The third field**
[image: 2. The field Avoir]

**3. The field_avoir settings**
[image: 3. field Avoir settings]

**4. The error**
[image: 4. The error message]

**Thank you**.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I found out what to do.
**Maybe this will help somebody else**.

- **I wrote this before :**

*$entity_field[0]["value"] = field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_nb_of_tickets");*

- **This is what's new :**

I did put the foreign field's value in a variable before adding it to the current field :

*$nb_of_tickets= field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, "field_nb_of_tickets");*

*$entity_field[0]["value"] = $entity_field[0]["value"] + $nb_of_tickets;*

Now it works.